# Как зациклить программу?

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы

Возник такой вопрос.
Как правильно применить цикл к программе?
Есть программа. Она делает:

1. Получает данные из файла .csv( в файле 4 столбца)
2. Обрабатывает данные.
3. Производит расчет.
4. Выводит ответ через print. (в ответе 4 результата. По числу столбцов)
   Как запустить программу 10, 20 ,30 .... раз. Получить ответы. И плюс , чтобы был еще и средний результат по каждому результату каждого столбца.

Я вот в интернете читал.
[Что читал, где искал](https://pythontutor.ru/lessons/while)
"https://pythontutor.ru/lessons/while
Но нет ни слова как зациклить всю программу.
Как это узнать ,понять. Моему разуму не понятно.
поэтому я и пишу о помощи.
Можно небольшой пример. Или ссылку.
Заранее благодарен.

Comment: не совсем понятно, вы бесконечно хотите зациклить? Тогда "while True:" Или какое-то определенное количество раз? Тогда лучше for

Comment: мне нужно ( я же написал) 10. 20. 30 и т.д. раз. Я не могу понять как это реализовать. плюс нужно чтобы после всех прогонов вывести среднее значение ответов по всем столбцам

Comment: 1) что это значит?? Вы на момент старта программы знаете конкретное количество раз, или оно в ходе выполнения программы определяется? Почему не конкретное число, а их перечень даны тут? 2) Вы с циклом for знакомы? Если да, то чем не устраивает он?

Comment: я сам хочу выбрать какой количество раз программа будет повторять действия.

Comment: и куда вставить цикл for. в начало. функцию отдельно создать. или как? я не понимаю.

Comment: тогда почитайте для начала нормальный учебник по Python - пару первых глав, иначе будет сложно. Я вполне серьёзно. Код тут не поместить, сейчас включу в ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой пример (смесь Python и псевдокода) без функции:

```
quantity = int(input ('Введите количество раз, которое программа будет повторять действия: '))
#тут храните накапливаемую сумму на каждом шаге цикла
result=0        
for i in range (quantity):
    Получает данные из файла .csv( в файле 4 столбца)
    Обрабатывает данные
    Производит расчет.
    result+=результат расчета 
    Выводит ответ через print (4 результата и средний)
result_final=result/quantity
print ('result final=', result_final)
```

Если какие-то из этих действий не надо повторять столько раз, сколько вы хотите, а всего раз сделать - вынесите их до "for i in range"

Comment: ОООгрумализированное спасибо. легко оказывается. Я дурачек))))

Comment: скорее, не занимались программированием особо:-) Этот алгоритм от языка не зависит:-)

Comment: А как сделать чтобы после каждого прогона. Ответ сохранялся и после всех прогонов выводилось среднее значение?

Comment: Добавил в ответ, но берите учебник. Это уже несерьёзно.

Comment: Спасибушки Человек. буду дальше учится.( хочется то все по быстрее)